# How to download a file from a remote server to a local folder on my mac using ssh

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm struggling to download a file from a remote server to a folder on my mac using ssh.

I've remoted onto the box successfully and browsed to the folder where the file I want to copy (`file1.txt`).

Running `ls`, I can see the file.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

So I've tried the following:

```
scp file1.txt /Users/me/test.txt
scp file1.txt /local/dir/Users/me/test.txt
```

I receive the following error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/Users/me/test.txt': No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

Run the `scp` command from your local machine, not the remote:

```
scp yourRemoteUserName@remoteIP:/path/to/file1.txt /Users/me/
```

If you *must* do it from the remote, you need to ensure that your local has an active `ssh` server and is accessible over the internet. If it is, you would reverse the command above and run:

```
scp /path/to/file1.txt yourLocalUserName@localIP:/Users/me/
```

Comment: So I'm trying from my local machine. Is there an easy way to find the 'path/to/file1.txt' as I generalized it in my original post and its quite nested. It's easy when remoted onto the box because I can cd into folders.

Comment: @Bhav what do you mean? Just `cd` into the folder on the remote, run `pwd` to get the full path, copy it, and then paste it in the local terminal.

Comment: Running `scp (username)@(server):/home/(username)/files/(folder1)/file1.txt /Users/(username)/` on my local machine, I get a `no matches found` error.

Comment: not sure if it makes a difference but I'm using zsh

Comment: In the file path above, the folder1 name contains . and square brackets however if I rename the folder to something basic like 'test', that appears to work.

Comment: @Bhav you need to quote it: `scp yourRemoteUserName@remoteIP:'/path/to/file1.txt' /Users/me/`

Comment: I still get the same error when quoting it. Is the full path case sensitive?

Comment: @Bhav yes, of course, all paths are always case sensitive in *nix systems.